# Error installing Windows7 64 bits on VirtualBox

Tags: 64-bit, virtualbox, windows-7

I am trying to set up Windows in Virtual Box, so I don't need to reboot in the rare occasion that I actually need it.

The problem is, Virtual Box doesn't preform any errors when I insert the 32bit installation CD but when I try to use the 64bit installation;

[image]

What!? I am already using the installation disc!

I've checked my BIOS to see if I have SVM (AMD's version of VT) disabled and all I see is "Enabled"

- I have a K9N6PGM2-V2 motherboard
- A Triple Core AMD Athlon II
- A Nvdia NForce 430 integrated graphics card
- 4GB of RAM
- An 80GB IDE
- And a 1TB SATA

I don't think the last three specifications matter but just in case XP

I am pretty sure the CD isn't broken ( I am going to make sure in just a moment ), what could be the cause to this problem?

**Edit:** The 64bit installation CD is not broken, but I found out when trying to install from the 32bit version that it's trying to upgrade, not preform a fresh install - Odd.

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu?. Have you checked Activate Vt-x/AMD-V in VirtualBox configuration (Systema->Acceleration).

Comment: What's wrong about using 32-bit Windows XP in VBox?

Comment: Please improve your question title and description, your problem root is the Windows 7 installer not virtualbox.

Comment: I suggest you download and install the new [VirtualBox 4](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

I have found someone which had the same problem and resolved it by enabling the IO APIC in the VM system settings:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/virtualbox-2-1-on-fedora-64-bit-wont-install-windows-7-beta-64-bit-696358/

Comment: Thanks, I think you have a typo though because enabling it worked, not disabling it.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure your Ubuntu installation is 64 bit, too. You can still run 32bit VMs, then. Running 64bit VMs under a 32 bit host system doesn't work, thorugh.

Comment: Uh... yes it does.

Comment: You can run a 64 bit VM on a 32 bit host IF the processor supports VT and x64 instructions.